# Issues in textareas editing

Tags: javascript, dom-events, textarea

I'm making a kind of text editor in a textarea where I process user input, including tabs. Every time the user inputs something, I run a `paginate()` function which paginates the text correctly on the page, this function takes about 20 milliseconds. Now, because I don't want a second input to be processed while the textarea is being paginated I've added a condition but that way I'm losing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-V</kbdI functionality. So, following a suggestion by @Gabriel Gartz at this post: [textarea on input issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185964/textarea-on-input-issue).

I call again the function by saving first the context and the event. The function does get called again, but the paste still doesn't take place!

html:

```
<textarea id="taEditor"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#taEditor").on('click keydown cut paste', processUserInput);

var IsProcessingEvent = false;

function processUserInput(e) {
    if(!IsProcessingEvent) {
        IsProcessingEvent = true;
        //do various stuff before the textarea changes like: get value, get   cursor pos etc
        var taValueBefore = document.getElementById("taEditor").value;
        if (e.keyCode === 9) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          document.getElementById("taEditor").value += "\t";
        }
        getcursorpos();
 
        //do various stuff after the textarea changes like: get value, get   cursor pos etc  
        setTimeout(function() {
            var taValueAfter = document.getElementById("taEditor").value;
            getcursorpos();
          if (taValueAfter !== taValueBefore) {
            paginate(); //this function paginates the text in the textarea and sets the cursor
            //paginate() takes about 20 milliseconds
          }
          if (doAgain.repeat) {
            var lastEvent = doAgain;
            doAgain.repeat = false;
            document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML += "rerun: " + lastEvent.ctx.id + ":" + lastEvent.e.type + "<br>";
            setTimeout(processUserInput.bind(lastEvent.ctx), 0, lastEvent.e);
          }
          document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML += e.type + "<br>";
          IsProcessingEvent = false;
        }, 0);
    } else {
      //save context and event
      document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML += "isprocessing: " + e.type + "<br>";
          doAgain = {
            ctx: this,
            e: e,
                  repeat: true
      };
      //i need to preventdefault here, because processUerInput also processes the TAB key and if i don't use preventdefault then the cursor will move focus to other elements during the pagination
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
}

var doAgain = {
    ctx: "",
    e: "",
    repeat: false
};

function getcursorpos() {
  //for simplicity reasons it's empty
}

function paginate() {
  var i = 0;
  var k = 0;
  //simulate 20-30 milliseconds of delay for pagination
  for (i=0;i<100000000;i++) {
    k++;
  }
  //for simplicity reasons it's empty
}
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/63pkE/1/

**to reproduce the problem: try to ctrl-v in the textarea.**

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

***EDIT***

Here is a new jsfiddle where I replaced the

```
        setTimeout(processUserInput.bind(lastEvent.ctx), 0, lastEvent.e);
```

line with

```
        setTimeout(function() {
          processUserInput.call(lastEvent.ctx, lastEvent.e);
        }, 0);
```

since `.bind` is not crossbrowser and still it DOESN'T work.

http://jsfiddle.net/63pkE/2/

Comment: Where are you using _Promises_? It's in the title, but never mentioned.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen corrected the title.

Comment: FWIW, use `e.which`, not `e.keyCode`

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if if works, I didn't notice any difference from your original code behavior and copy paste work now.

```
function processUserInput(e) {
    if(!IsProcessingEvent) {
        if(!e.ctrlKey){
            IsProcessingEvent = true;
        }
    //Rest of the code
```

e.ctrlKey returns true if the Ctrl key is pressed.